# Should Maybe.map respect the mapped value?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

For a Maybe.Just monad, if we map it with a function returning null, it will still return Just with null inside, but I think it should be Nothing, otherwise it lost its power to protect against null. Am I right, or there is another reason to be like that?

```
Maybe.fromNuallable({noname: ''}) // return Just({noname: ''})
.map(prop('name')) // return Just(undefined), but I think it should return Nothing()
.map(x=>x.length) // failed here
```

I checked all the implementations (falktale and ramda.fantasy) of Maybe.map, it is the below:

```
Just.prototype.map = function(f) {
  return this.of(f(this.value));
};
```

Comment: I rewrote my answer to better illustrate the subject - mainly for myself. Maybe its helpful for others too.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks, esp. the last sentance hit the point: every function that might return null/undefined should return an Option type, so that this behavior becomes explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I might be wrong but `map` comes from Functors. So it operates on simple morphism not kleisli arrows. You need to use `bind` and some sort of a function that returns a monad

```
// maybeProp:: String -> A -> Maybe[B]
const maybeProp = name => val => Maybe.fromNullable(val[name])

Maybe
  .fromNullable({noname: ''})
  .bind(maybeProp('name'))
  .map(x => x.length)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think "bind" is equivalent to "chain" (which is defined in fantasyland). "bind" apply the passing function on the inside value and return a monad (in this case, it is Maybe). So If I worry about the function will generate null value, I should use "bind" instead of "map".

Comment: @Ron right. It seems `chain` defined in fantasyland is `bind`. `map` aka `fmap` is not enough because you want to treat inner nulls and undefineds ans Maybes. So you need full power of monad to "smash" M[M[A]] into M[A].

Comment: @LUH3417 This looks like a valid usecase for Maybe. Why "misuse"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a greatly simplified implementation of the `Maybe` (aka `Option`) data type for teaching:

```js
class Option {
  constructor(x) { this.x = x }
  isNone() { return this.x === null || this.x === undefined }
  map(f) { return this.isNone() ? this : this.of(f(this.x)) }
  ap(ftor) { return this.isNone() ? this : ftor.map(this.x) }
  of(x) { return Option.of(x) }
  flatten() { return this.isNone() ? this : this.x }
  chain(mf) { return this.isNone() ? this : this.map(mf).flatten() }
}

Option.of = x => new Option(x);

const o = new Option({}),
 p = new Option({name: "foo"});

const prop = key => o => new Option(o[key]),
 len = prop("length");

// 
let r1 = o.map(prop("name")).map(x => x.map(len)),
 r2 = p.map(prop("name")).map(x => x.map(len));

console.log(r1);
console.log(r2);

let r3 = o.chain(prop("name")).chain(len);
r4 = p.chain(prop("name")).chain(len);

console.log(r3);
console.log(r4);
```

- `o` and `p` are `Option` types and implement the functor, applicative functor and monad interface
- `prop` and `len` are Kleisli arrows that is, functions that return a monad (namely an `Option` monad in this case)
- when you apply `prop`/`len` to `o`/`p` via their functor interface (`map`), then this yields a nested `Option` type (see `r1`/`r2`)
- to avoid this behavior you need to apply Kleisli arrows via `chain` (the monadic interface), which is a sequence of `map` and `flatten` (see `r3`/`r4`)
- every function that might return `null`/`undefined` should return an `Option` type, so that this behavior becomes explicit

Comment: I might be wrong, but many books told me, Maybe/Either is the functional way to handle error/exception. What's more, how about if the object(I mean the object {name: 'john'}) is passed in, and I cannot control if it is the right scheme.

Comment: @Ron You're right. `Maybe/Either` is used to handle expected exceptions (which might occur). If you can't control the object scheme, than this isn't a runtime exception. I think I need to examine the subject a little closer and then rewrite/delete my answer.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I am learning FP, it looks easy, but lots of issues rise when I try to use it in the real world.